# Keras How To Resume Training With Adam Optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

My model requires to run many epochs in order to get decent result, and it takes few hours using v100 on Google Cloud.

Since I'm on a preemptible instance, it kicks me off in the middle of training. I would like to be able to resume from where it left off.

In my custom CallBack, I run self.model.save(...) in on_epoch_end. Also it stops the training if the score hasn't improved in last 50 epochs.

Here are the steps I tried:

1. I ran model.fit until the early stops kicked in after epoch 250 (best score was at epoch 200)
2. I loaded the model saved after 100th epoch.
3. I ran model.fit with initial_epoch=100. (It starts with Epoch 101.)

However, it takes while to catch up with the first run. Also the accuracy score of each epoch gets kind of close to the first run, but it's lower. Finally the early stop kicked in at like 300, and the final score is lower than the first run. Only way I can get the same final score is to create the model from scratch and run fit from the epoch 1.

I also tried to utilize float(K.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr)) and K.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, new_lr).
However, self.model.optimizer.lr always returned the same number. I assume it's because the adam optimizer calculates the real lr from the initial lr that I set with Adam(lr=1e-4).

I'm wondering what's the right approach to resume training using Adam optimizer?

Answer (score 5):

> I'm wondering what's the right approach to resume training using Adam optimizer?

As mentioned here: https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model, `model.save()` followed by `load_model()` will take care of compiling the model using the saved training configuration.

```
if not os.path.exists('tf_keras_cifar10.h5'):
    model = get_model() #this method constructs the model and compiles it 
else:
    model = load_model('tf_keras_cifar10.h5') #load the model from file
    print('lr is ', K.get_session().run(model.optimizer.lr))
    initial_epoch=10
    epochs=13

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,validation_data=(x_test, y_test), initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
model.save('tf_keras_cifar10.h5')
```

- At the end of initial run just before saving the model

Epoch 10/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 13s 255us/sample - loss: 0.6257 - acc: 0.7853 - val_loss: 0.8886 - val_acc: 0.6985

- Resuming from saved model:

Epoch 11/13
50000/50000 [==============================] - 15s 293us/sample - loss: 0.6438 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 0.8732 - val_acc: 0.7083

Please check this issue as well related to resuming training using Adam Optimizer(tf.keras): https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27049

The recommendation is to upgrade the TF version.

Comment: If you run few epochs like the example you provided, it appears it's working, but if you run an example requiring many epochs like 100 or more, it gets off quite a bit though. I'm using Tensorflow v1.13.1. I haven't tried Tensorflow 2.0 beta yet.

Comment: will the `initial_epoch` arg work with a "fresh" optimizer and loading only the weights of the model via `load_weights()`?
I'm asking bc my model h5 file got corrupted due to a VM crash during saving, and I was left with only the weights h5 file (a separate file)... :/

Answer (score 0):

What about `model.load('saved.h5')`. It should also load the optimizer if you save it with `model.save()` though.

Comment: You mean tf.keras.models.load_model? That's what I'm using, but it's not working as expected. I suspect it's because LR doesn't get restored and starts from the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

- About `self.model.optimizer.lr` : it returns the initial learning rate that you set, the actual learning rate used on an epoch and gradient is calculated from it.
- Adam optimizer uses more variables than just the learning rate, so to be sure to recover its state completely you can call `model.optimizer`
- A good practice is to initialize a model and optimizer and then update the state dictionaries using your checkpoint :

  ```
   # ============ Load Checkpoint ============
   model = keras.models.load_model('trained_model.h5')
   # get weights
   modelWeights = model.get_weights()
   # get optimizer state as it was on last epoch
   modelOptimizer = model.optimizer

   # ============ Compile Model ============
   # redefine architecture (newModel=models.Sequential(), etc.)
   newModel= redefine_your_model_architecture()
   # compile
   newModel.compile(optimizer=modelOptimizer,
                    loss=loss,
                    metrics=['accuracy'])
   # set trained weights
   newModel.set_weights(modelWeights)

   # ============ Resume Training ============
   history = newModel.fit(...)
  ```

> IMPORTANT: You cannot reproduce exactly the same training (loss, accuracy, etc.) on GPUs using Tensorflow, as explained here: [Keras_reproducibility](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development)

> **In short**: GPUs run many operations in parallel, so the order of execution is not always guaranteed. Due to the limited precision of floats, even adding several numbers together may give slightly different results depending on the order in which you add them

> PyTorch on the other hand do have a functionality to fix this order of execution in CuDNN settings, as explained here: [PyTorch_reproducibility](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html)